# The proof of $\text{lim sup}\frac{\lambda (B)}{m (B)} =0$ if $\lambda$ is singular to $m$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How to prove the following:

> $\lambda$ is a measure on $R^d$ which is singular w.r.t lebesgue measure $m$.  Then $\text{lim sup}_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\lambda (B(r,x))}{m (B(r,x))} =0$ $m$-almost everywhere.

Note: $B(r,x)$ is a ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

Could anyone provide me with the first step or a hint?

Does it relate to the shrinking rate?

Comment: Is this $\lambda$-almost everywhere or $m$-almost everywhere?

Comment: Should be m-almost everywhere

Comment: First step: Consider the set where the $\limsup_{r\to 0}$ of the quotient is $\geq 1/n$.

Comment: @PhoemueX And then prove the measure of the set where the quotient $\geq  0 \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Also by Vitali covering lemma